# Convert 2020-10-18T21:00:00.000-03:00 to 2020-10-19T00:00

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-fns

As you can see in the image, I'm getting an array of dates from my API, which I need to show on the frontend, but in my actual timezone, which is America/Sao_Paulo. The problem is, I can't figure out how to do this using date-fns and date-fns-tz. I've had some tries, but with no success.

Example:

From

> 2020-10-18T21:00:00.000-03:00

To

> 2020-10-19T00:00

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4MwW.png)

Some code I wrote, but didn't work:

```
    const lastParsedDate = parseISO(dates[dates.length - 1])

    const tzTime = utcToZonedTime(lastParsedDate, 'America/Sao_Paulo')

    console.log(lastParsedDate, tzTime)
```

Comment: `2020-10-18T21:00:00.000-03:00` is *already* in terms of local time in São Paulo.  Converting it to `2020-10-19T00:00` would give the equivalent UTC time (though it should have a `Z` at the end).   Are you trying to get the UTC time?  If so, you don't need date-fns at all. `new Date("2020-10-18T21:00:00.000-03:00").toISOString()` will work fine.